# toggle effect in jQuery for 2 div

Tags: jquery

I have make a jquery toggle  efect. When I click one div it toggles and when I click another div it also toggles but both are open. So my question if I open one of them then the second div will be close automatically. [My demo link is here](http://jsfiddle.net/r7s1b47w/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.top').each(function(index) {
      $(this).on("click", function(){
         $('.read:eq(' + index + ')').slideToggle("fast");
      });
   });
});

$('.box').click(function (e) {
   $( '#' + $(this).data('toggleTarget') ).slideToggle(300);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to bind events inside a loop structure.

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.top').on('click', function () {
        $('.read').not($('.read:eq(' + $('.top').index(this) + ')').slideToggle(300)).slideUp(300);
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r7s1b47w/1/)

Comment: *Don't try to bind events inside a loop structure.* Why?

Comment: @Xlander We can do that.. but if you miss to create a scope per iteration, then the events which are bound, would always work with the data present in the last iteration of the loop..

Answer (score 0):

You need to `slideUp()` other divs. also you dont need to iterate over them to set the click event. Use:

```
 $('.top').click(function(index){
           $('.read:not(:eq('+$('.top').index(this)+'))').slideUp();
           $('.read:eq(' + $('.top').index(this) + ')').slideToggle("fast");
     });
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mdse5w3g/)**